# How to tell which processes was created by a specific file?

Tags: windows-10, process

For example, ProcessActivityView (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/process_activity_view.html) creates a summary of all files and folders that the selected process tries to access.

Conversely, I would like to create a summary of all processes that the selected files have started.

To be more specific, here is what I need:

I would like select a group of files, and then when I click on "start monitoring", the software could tell me which processes have been created by those files, and what are the new files created by those files.

Comment: In  task manager, you can right click on the process and choose open file location.

Comment: @Peter.G I don't know what is the name of that process; I need to find the name of the process from a known filename.

Answer (score 1):

As a trick, you can loop through all the running processes in the task manager, and check (for every process) if the file name that in "Open file location" is included in your selected files list.

But note that this is not a perfect solution, because:

1. It is possible that one file calls another file that starts a process..
2. It is O(n^2)